# BottomNavigationView Icon/Text Animation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The selected icons and text of my BottomNavigationView shift and get bigger when selected. I couldn't find a setting in the Attributes to turn the animation off. How can I change this?
The BottomNavigationView uses fragments and looks like this:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        app:itemRippleColor="#00FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />
```

The MainActivity.java looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Sets the Bottom Navigation
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" for Bottom Navigation View in your xml code . It will remove the item horizontal translation

Also (optional) you can fix your icon sizes for selected and non selected state with this line : app:itemIconSize="20dp"

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        app:itemRippleColor="#00FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

Comment: Okay if you don't want the title to appear use this line app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled" instead of app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" . Also to know more about any xml tag and its possible values just click on the tag and then press Ctrl+q for options.